# RedGate SQL Data Generator Python Script Check datetime column for null

Tags: python, sql-server, redgate, data-generation

I'm using RedGate SQL Data Generator to generate test data in SQL Server 2016. I have a table with a nullable DATETIME column called DELETE_TS. Another column, IUD_CODE, is CHAR(1). In production, that column is "D" when DELETE_TS is not null. Otherwise it is either "I" or "U" depending on some other logic.

To create "realistic" test data, I am trying to use a Python Script generator to create that logic. I'm currently using:

```
def main(config):
    if DELETE_TS is None:
        return "U"
    else:
        return "D"
```

But EVERY column comes up "D", even when DELETE_TS is null.

I haven't done much in Python before, so I'm sure it's something small I'm missing.

EDIT: Here is the DDL for the relevant columns in the table:

```
  CREATE TABLE dbo.DIM_MERCHANT (
  DELETE_TS DATETIME NULL,
  IUD_CODE CHAR(1) NULL
  )
```

Comment: Please post ddl - I have the Red Gate tools and can give this a shot.

Answer (score 1):

This works in python generator.

```
def main(config):
if DELETE_TS:
    return "D"
else:
    return "U"
```